# How to connect to an IP Address of a SignalR server using ng2 SignalR in Angular 2

Tags: angular, signalr

I have created a SignalR application in angular using ng2. It is running correctly as of now. My problem lies on the fact that it can connect to a hard coded Ip Address. I need to dynamically supply the IP Address so I can connect to any server on a given time. In the documentation of ng2, the SignalR configuration is in the app.module.ts. That means there is no way to change it anymore on runtime. I am connecting on "tabs1" page. Please see my code below on how I am implementing this.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SignalRModule } from 'ng2-signalr';
import { SignalRConfiguration } from 'ng2-signalr';

export function createConfig(): SignalRConfiguration {
  const config = new SignalRConfiguration();
  config.hubName = 'ServerHub';
  config.qs = { user: 'Lane' };
  config.url = 'http://localhost:8089/'; <=== This is the URL of the server that I need to dynamically change
  config.executeEventsInZone = true;
  config.executeErrorsInZone = false;
  config.executeStatusChangeInZone = true;
  return config;
}
```

**connection.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { SignalR, IConnectionOptions, BroadcastEventListener } from 'ng2-signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnectionService {
  messageReceived: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  messageFromServer = new Subject<string>();
  options: IConnectionOptions = { hubName: 'ServerHub' };
  onMessageReceived$ = new BroadcastEventListener<string>('Addmessage');
  onServerBroadcast$ = new BroadcastEventListener('serverBroadcast');
  connection: any = null;
  public message = '';

  constructor(
    private signalR: SignalR
  ) { }

  public startConnection(): void {
    this.connection = this.signalR.createConnection();
    this.connection.start().then((c: { errors: { hasError: any; }; }) => {
      if(!c.errors.hasError) {
        // this.connection.listen(this.onMessageReceived$);
        this.connection.listen(this.onServerBroadcast$);

        this.onMessageReceived$.subscribe((message: string) => {
          console.log('asdfasdf' + message);
        });

        this.onServerBroadcast$.subscribe((message: any) => {
          this.message = this.message + message;
          this.messageFromServer.next(this.message);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  public MessageFromClient(message: string): void {
    this.connection.invoke('messageFromClient', message)
      .then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  public getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

**tab1.component.ts**

```
import {
  SignalR,
  BroadcastEventListener,
  IConnectionOptions
} from 'ng2-signalr';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ConnectionService } from '../../_services/connection.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

 message = '';
  options: IConnectionOptions = { hubName: 'ServerHub' };
  onMessageSent$ = new BroadcastEventListener<string>('addMessage');
  private messageFromServerSubscription: Subscription;
  ipAddress: string;

onSubmit(form: NgForm){
    if(!form.valid) {
      return;
    }
    this.ipAddress = form.value;
    console.log(this.ipAddress);
    this.cs.startConnection(); <=== This is how I start the connection
  }
```